# scrambling images on canvas producing whitespace

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm starting with a `canvas` element. I'm making the left half red, and the right side blue. Every half second, `setInterval` calls a function, scramble, which splits both RHS and LHS into pieces, and shuffles them.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aeq1g3yb/

The code is below. The reason I'm using `window.onload` is because this thing is supposed to scramble pictures and I want the pictures to load first. I'm using colors *here* because of the cross-origin business that I don't know enough about, so this is my accommodation.

```
var n = 1;
var v = 1;

function scramble() {

  //get the canvas and change its width
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  c.width = 600;
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  //drawing 2 different colors side by side
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width/2, c.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(c.width/2, 0, c.width/2, c.height);

  //how big will each shuffled chunk be
  var stepsA = (c.width/2) / n;
  var stepsB = (c.width/2) / n;
  var step = stepsA + stepsB;

  var imgDataA = [];
  var imgDataB = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var imgDataElementA = ctx.getImageData(stepsA*i, 0, stepsA, c.height);
    var imgDataElementB = ctx.getImageData(c.width/2+stepsB*i, 0, stepsB, c.height);
    imgDataA.push(imgDataElementA);
    imgDataB.push(imgDataElementB);
  }

  //clearing out the canvas before laying on the new stuff
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  //put the images back
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ctx.putImageData(imgDataA[i], step*i, 0);
    ctx.putImageData(imgDataB[i], step*i+stepsA, 0);
  }

  //gonna count the steps
  var count = document.getElementById("count");
  count.innerHTML = n;

  n += v;

  if (n >= 100 || n <= 1) {
    v *= -1;
  }

}; //closing function scramble

window.onload = function() { //gotta do this bc code executes before image loads
  scramble();
};

window.setInterval(scramble, 500);
```

More or less, this thing works the way I want it to. But there is one problem: Sometimes there are vertical white lines.

My question is:

Why are there white lines? If you view the fiddle, you will see the degree to which this impairs the effect of the shuffle.

Comment: In a word, anti-aliasing. Try to ensure your rectangles have vertices that are on integers, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @Patrick Robert, This seems to have worked. I made the width of the canvas 512 so each half is 256, and I just divide it by power of 2. It's a bit faster than I would like but it does not produce any white lines.

Comment: You don't have to use a power of 2. Just try to use `Math.round()` / `Math.floor()` / `Math.ceil()` strategically, it'll still look okay.

Comment: I think I will need to be creative, as you suggest. Because while dividing by powers of 2 works in the above example, with red and blue, where both sections are of equal width, it doesn't work well with images (which I'm running locally). I'll need to be creative because even if I can fix the width of both images combined to a number with lots of factors, both images would need to be a width which have the same factors since they must be (in this simple operation) divided into the same number of sections so the scrambling works. But at least I have an intuitive grasp of the problem.

Comment: [`ctx.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) allows you to scale the images as well, don't forget to take advantage of that.

Comment: in one I'm running locally, inside my function I use both ctx.getImageData and ctx.putImageData (tried ctx.drawImage which didn't work there) to layer the elements of the array. that's the original thing I started with. If I can't figure it out I might open a new question, but the fact that I don't know how to getImageData in the fiddle (that cross-origins stuff) makes it difficult.

Comment: I meant for the original images, not for all your operations.

Comment: I use drawImage to stick the images to the canvas initially in the program, from which i getImageData, then clear canvas, and putImageData. But I actually just fixed the width of each image to 256 and it turned out all right. If I'm interested in getting this to work without that step, I might open a new question after trying the creative stuff. I appreciate that you showed me what the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can`t divide a Pixel

The problem can be solve but will introduce some other artifacts as you can not divide integer pixels into fractions.

#### Quick solution

The following solution for your existing code rounds down for the start of a section and up for the width.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var imgDataElementA = ctx.getImageData(
        Math.floor(stepsA * i), 0, 
        Math.ceil(stepsA + stepsA * i)  - Math.floor(stepsA * i), c.height
    );
    var imgDataElementB = ctx.getImageData(
        Math.floor(c.width / 2 + stepsB * i), 0, 
        Math.ceil(c.width / 2 + stepsB * i + stepsB) - Math.floor(c.width / 2 + stepsB * i), c.height);
    imgDataA.push(imgDataElementA);
    imgDataB.push(imgDataElementB);
  }
```

#### Quicker options

But doing this via the pixel image data is about the slowest possible way you could find to do it. You can just use the 2D context.imageDraw function to do the movement for you. Or if you want the best in terms of performance a WebGL solution would be the best with the fragment shader doing the scrambling for you as a parallel solution.

#### There is no perfect solution

But in the end you can not cut a pixel in half, there are a wide range of ways to attempt to solve this but each method has its own artifacts. Ideally you should only slice an image if the rule `image.width % slices === 0` in all other cases you will have one or more slices that will not fit on an integer number of pixels.

#### Example of 4 rounding methods.

The demo shows 4 different methods and with 2 colors. Mouse over to see a closer view. Each method is separated horizontally with a white line. Hold the mouse button to increase the slice counter.

The top is your original.
The next three are 3 different ways of dealing with the fractional pixel width.

```js
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}
function mouseEvents(e){
    const m = mouse;
    if(m.element){
     m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
     m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left - scrollX;
     m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top - scrollY;
     m.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : m.button;
    }
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse"+name,mouseEvents));

const counterElement = document.getElementById("count");

// get constants for the demo
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
mouse.element = c;
// The image with the blue and red
const img = document.createElement("canvas");
// the zoom image overlay
const zoom = document.createElement("canvas");
// the scrambled image
const scram = document.createElement("canvas");
// Set sizes and get context
const w = scram.width = zoom.width = img.width = c.width = 500;
const h = scram.height = zoom.height = img.height = c.height;
const dCtx = c.getContext("2d");  // display context
const iCtx = img.getContext("2d");  // source image context
const zCtx = zoom.getContext("2d"); // zoom context
const sCtx = scram.getContext("2d"); // scrambled context

// some constants
const zoomAmount = 4;
const zoomRadius = 60;
const framesToStep = 10;

function createTestPattern(ctx){
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width/2, c.height/2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(c.width/2, 0, c.width/2, c.height/2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, c.height/2, c.width/2, c.height/2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#CCC";
  ctx.fillRect(c.width/2, c.height/2, c.width/2, c.height/2);
}
createTestPattern(iCtx);
sCtx.drawImage(iCtx.canvas, 0, 0);
// Shows a zoom area so that blind men like me can see what is going on.
function showMouseZoom(src,dest,zoom = zoomAmount,radius = zoomRadius){
  dest.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
  dest.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  if(mouse.x >= 0 && mouse.y >= 0 && mouse.x < w && mouse.y < h){
      dest.setTransform(zoom,0,0,zoom,mouse.x,mouse.y)
      dest.drawImage(src.canvas, -mouse.x, -mouse.y);
      dest.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
      dest.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
      dest.beginPath();
      dest.arc(mouse.x,mouse.y,radius,0,Math.PI * 2);
      dest.fill();
      dest.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      dest.lineWidth = 4;
      dest.strokeStyle = "black";
      dest.stroke();
  }
  
}


function scramble(src,dest,y,height) {
 const w = src.canvas.width;
  const h = src.canvas.height;
  const steps = (w/2) / slices;
  dest.fillStyle = "white";
  dest.fillRect(0, y, w, height);

  for (var i = 0; i < slices * 2; i++) {      
      dest.drawImage(src.canvas,
          ((i / 2) | 0) * steps + (i % 2) * (w / 2)- 0.5, y,
          steps + 1, height,
          i * steps - 0.5, y,
          steps+ 1, height
      );
  }
}
function scrambleFloor(src,dest,y,height) {
 const w = src.canvas.width;
  const h = src.canvas.height;
  const steps = (w/2) / slices;
  dest.fillStyle = "white";
  dest.fillRect(0, y, w, height);

  for (var i = 0; i < slices * 2; i++) {      
      dest.drawImage(src.canvas,
          (((i / 2) | 0) * steps + (i % 2) * (w / 2)- 0.5) | 0, y,
          steps + 1, height,
          (i * steps - 0.5) | 0, y,
          steps + 1, height
      );
  }
}
function scrambleNoOverlap(src,dest,y,height) {
  const w = src.canvas.width;
  const h = src.canvas.height;
  const steps = (w / 2) / slices;
  dest.fillStyle = "white";
  dest.fillRect(0, y, w, height);

  for (var i = 0; i < slices * 2; i++) {      
      dest.drawImage(src.canvas,
          ((i / 2) | 0) * steps + (i % 2) * (w / 2), y,
          steps, height,
          i * steps - 0.5, y,
          steps, height
      );
  }
}


function scrambleOriginal(src,dest,y,height) {
  const w = src.canvas.width;
  const h = src.canvas.height;

  //how big will each shuffled chunk be
  var stepsA = (w/2) / slices;
  var stepsB = (w/2) / slices;
  var step = stepsA + stepsB;

  var imgDataA = [];
  var imgDataB = [];
   
  for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++) {
    var imgDataElementA = src.getImageData(stepsA*i, y, stepsA, height);
    var imgDataElementB = src.getImageData(w/2+stepsB*i, y, stepsB, height);
    imgDataA.push(imgDataElementA);
    imgDataB.push(imgDataElementB);
  }

  //clearing out the canvas before laying on the new stuff
  dest.fillStyle = "white";
  dest.fillRect(0, y, w, height);

  //put the images back
  for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++) {
    dest.putImageData(imgDataA[i], step*i, y);
    dest.putImageData(imgDataB[i], step*i+stepsA, y);
  }



}; //closing function scramble



const scrambleMethods = [scrambleOriginal,scramble,scrambleFloor,scrambleNoOverlap];


var frameCount = 0;
var sliceStep = 1;
var slices = 1;
function mainLoop(){
    if(mouse.button){
        if(frameCount++ % framesToStep === framesToStep-1){  // every 30 Frames
            slices += sliceStep;
            if(slices > 150 || slices < 2){ sliceStep = -sliceStep }
            counterElement.textContent = slices; // Prevent reflow  by using textContent
            sCtx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
            sCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
            const len = scrambleMethods.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i ++){
                scrambleMethods[i](iCtx,sCtx,(128/len) * i, 128/len-2);
                scrambleMethods[i](iCtx,sCtx,(128/len) * i + 128, 128/len-2);
            }
        }
    }
    dCtx.fillStyle = "white";
    dCtx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

    dCtx.drawImage(sCtx.canvas,0,0);
    showMouseZoom(dCtx,zCtx);
    dCtx.drawImage(zCtx.canvas,0,0);
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

}
//scramble(iCtx,sCtx);
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#count {
  position : absolute;
  top : 0px;
  left : 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height = "256" title="Hold mouse button to chance slice count"></canvas>

<p id="count"></p>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the depth of your answer. I haven't been using the canvas tag this way for too long and I'm still playing around with the code you've written. These other approaches are very exciting for me. I haven't measured it, but I noticed when I slice images up, the way I've been doing it, it does lag. And there is, as you've said, there is the ultimate problem of not being able to split a pixel, which is something I'll have to dance around.